# Silverlight Converting a value using Thresholds

Tags: c#, silverlight, ivalueconverter

I'm attempting to convert a value using two threshold values, the call to the database will return three variables

```
Double Score;
Double LowerThreshold;
Double HigherThreshold;
```

If the score is lower than the lower threshold then a red image will be shown, if it's between the two thresholds then amber will be shown and if higher than the higher threshold then green will be shown.

Currently i'm using a custom ValueConverter but i'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. I merge the high and low thresholds together so that they look like this "30,50" and then parse the values from the string and work out which image to display.

This is the code i'm using for the ValueConverter

```
public class ScoreConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            if (parameter is string)
            {
                if ((parameter as string).Contains(",")) 
                {
                    string[] thresholds = (parameter as string).Split(',');

                    int lowerThreshold;
                    int upperThreshold;

                    bool success;

                    success = int.TryParse(thresholds[0], out lowerThreshold);
                    if (!success)
                        return "Error";
                    success = int.TryParse(thresholds[1], out upperThreshold);
                    if (!success)
                        return "Error";

                    if ((double)value < lowerThreshold)
                    {
                        //red
                        return "/Red32.png";
                    }
                    else if ((double)value > upperThreshold)
                    {
                        //green
                        return "/Green32.png";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //amber
                        return "/Amber32.png";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "Error";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "Not Possible";
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for a better approach would be appreciated,

Thanks

**EDIT**

Decided to use the following code, the server returns the following structure

```
public class ScoreInformation
{
    public double Score { get; set; }

    public double lowerThreshold { get; set; }

    public double upperThreshold { get; set; }

}
```

And this is the code that converts it and displays the correct image

```
    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is ScoreInformation)
        {
            ScoreInformation si = (ScoreInformation)value;

            if (si.Score < si.lowerThreshold)
            {
                return "Red32.png";
            }
            else if (si.Score > si.upperThreshold)
            {
                //green
                return "Green32.png";
            }
            else
            {
                //amber
                return "Orange32.png";
            }
        }

        return "Grey32.png";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is certainly one way to do it, especially if the ranges are going to change each time you use the binding, however, if you're going to re-use the same values over and over you can declare properties on your value converter and set them on initialization.

```
public int upperThreshold { get; set; }
public int lowerThreshold { get; set; }

public string lowImage { get; set; }
public string middleImage { get; set; }
public string highImage { get; set; }

public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {

            if ((double)value < lowerThreshold)
            {
                //red
                return lowImage;
            }
            else if ((double)value > upperThreshold)
            {
                //green
                return highImage;
            }
            else
            {
                //amber
                return middleImage;
            }

        }
        return "Error";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "Not Possible";
    }
}

<local:RangeToImageConverter
    x:Name="MyRangeConverter"
    upperThreshold="30"
    lowerThreshold="50"
    lowImage="/red32.png"
    middleImage="/amber32.png"
    highImage="/green32.png"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, is it possible to assign to those properties using data bindings? I've currently hit a problem with my initial code, it works fine if I hard code the thresholds but I can't seem to assign them using bindings which I need to do

Comment: I'm really not sure. If you try, I'd love to know if it works or not, just make sure that you change the properties to dependency properties and make your value converter inherit from DependencyObject (in addition to implementing IValueConverter)

Comment: I decided to try another way, the 3 variables returned from the server are wrapped in a small class, I then perform the conversion on that class which contains the thresholds and the initial score. It seemed like the best way at the time. 
I'm going to mark yours as the answer as it was really helpful.